# how to use aidl to convert ITelephony.aidl to ITelephony.java

Tags: android, command-line, aidl

I downloaded android source code trying to understand how stub class works for android telephony system, so I use aidl convert ITelephony.aidl but it gives me error such as:

couldn't find import for class android.os.Bundle;

couldn't find import for class android.telephony.NeighboringCellInfo;

couldn't find import for class android.telephony.CellInfo;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to let the `aidl` command know the location of those classes.

For example, for `class android.os.Bundle`, try following:

```
aidl -pandroid_sdk/platforms/android-19/framework.aidl ITelephony.aidl
```

Similarly, search *.aidl for those containing

```
parcelable android.telephony.NeighboringCellInfo;
parcelable android.telephony.CellInfo;
```

and pass them to the `aidl` command.